# How to place a Logo of a university at the bottom right of a poster?

Tags: fonts, header-footer, minipage, tikzposter

I am using the UWtheme for posters. I need to move the logo of the uni. from the top right to the bottom left and write to the left of the logo the name of the Dept. like this photo below of MIT's.

[image: output of the code]

[image: MIT EXAMPLE]

Also, if I want to move the name to the left. How can I change that in the main code?

```
\documentclass[20pt,margin=1in,innermargin=-4.5in,blockverticalspace=-0.25in]{tikzposter}
\geometry{paperwidth=42in,paperheight=32.5in}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{uwtheme}
\usepackage{mwe} % for placeholder images
%\addbibresource{refs.bib}

% set theme parameters
\tikzposterlatexaffectionproofoff
\usetheme{UWTheme}
\usecolorstyle{UWStyle}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\title{{\fontsize{100}{60}\selectfont Dangerous stuff}}
 
\author{\bfseries Name - position \textsuperscript{$\dagger$}}
\institute{\textsuperscript{$\dagger$} Department  -  University}
\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[width=0.06\textwidth]{alex.png}}


\begin{document}

\maketitle


\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome. I think it would be better to include a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that), so we can help you more easily.

Comment: Thank you. I made some changes in the code

Comment: Where can the `uwtheme` file be found?